# Строки выводятся через одну. Как вывести все строки из файла?

Tags: php

```
$f = fopen("../log/path.log", "r");
while (fgets($f)) {
    echo fgets($f);}
fclose($f);
```

Файл log.path:

```
1480845953|http://mysite.local/index.php|/index.php?id=contact
1480845957|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=contact|/index.php
1480845959|http://mysite.local/index.php|/index.php?id=contact
1480845960|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=contact|/index.php?id=about
1480845961|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=about|/index.php?id=info
1480845963|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=info|/index.php
1480845966|http://mysite.local/index.php|/index.php?id=info
1480845969|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=info|/index.php?id=log
1480846037|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=info|/index.php?id=log
1480846042|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=info|/index.php?id=log
1480846045|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=info|/index.php?id=log
1480846076|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=info|/index.php?id=log
1480846079|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=info|/index.php?id=log
1480846121|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=info|/index.php?id=log
1480849480|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=log|/index.php?id=log
1480849495|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=log|/index.php?id=log
1480849514|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=log|/index.php?id=log
1480849612|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=log|/index.php?id=log
1480849622|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=log|/index.php?id=log
1480849640|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=log|/index.php?id=log
1480849909|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=log|/index.php?id=log
1480851576|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=log|/index.php?id=log
1480851584|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=log|/index.php?id=log
```

Результат:

```
1480845957|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=contact|/index.php
1480845960|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=contact|/index.php?id=about
1480845963|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=info|/index.php
1480845969|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=info|/index.php?id=log
1480846042|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=info|/index.php?id=log
1480846076|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=info|/index.php?id=log
1480846121|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=info|/index.php?id=log
1480849495|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=log|/index.php?id=log
1480849612|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=log|/index.php?id=log
1480849640|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=log|/index.php?id=log
1480851576|http://mysite.local/index.php?id=log|/index.php?id=log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопроса не прозвучало, поэтому пришлось стереть пыль с хрустального шара.

Данный код выводит строки через одну, поскольку вначале читается одна строка, проверяется в условии цикла `while`,  а потом читается другая и выводится командой `echo`.

Один из вариантов правильно работающего кода:

```
$f = fopen("../log/path.log", "r");
while ($l = fgets($f)) {
    echo $l;
}
```